# Drawing Specific Data from Large Spreadsheets?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with thousands of schools sorted by id numbers, with different data points across the rows. I need to transfer data from another sheet, where the same data  is listed in separate columns. So for each school, there is total, undergrad, grad enrollment, etc going across the row. But on the sheet I am drawing the data from, each of these categories has been assigned a number, and its own row. Basically, I cant just refer to the other sheet and drag down, and need a way to specifically refer to the right school and specific enrollment figure.

[Master Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqeDW.png)
[Sheet I am transferring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWSIi.png)

Comment: What sort of data do you have to start with? Do you have the ID and the name of the column that you need?

Comment: Suggest you go wtch the video at [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65). You should also read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Difficult to describe, the pictures I attached are the beginnings of the spreadsheets. I have attempted a VLOOKUP, but have been unsuccessful

Comment: "EFFYLEV refers to total, undergrad or grad, while "EFYTOTLT" is the enrollment number. "UNITID" is the university code. I am attempting to match these with their respective places on the other sheet.